# Why doesn't numeric_limits<T>::min() return the smallest value?

Tags: c++, numeric-limits

When I run this code:

```
#include <limits>
#include <cstdio>

#define T double

int main()
{
    static const T val = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
    printf( "%g/2 = %g\n", val, val/2 );
}
```

I would expect to see an unpredictable result. 
But I get the correct answer:

```
(16:53) > clang++ test_division.cpp -o test_division
(16:54) > ./test_division 
2.22507e-308/2 = 1.11254e-308
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min

Comment: @crhis Thank you, that was obvious but I never made this distinction between normalized/denormalized.. Learning every day, I guess another useful link is: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/denorm_min

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because `min` gives you the smallest *normalized* value.  You can still have smaller *denormalized* values (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalized_number).

Comment: Of course, this doesn't explain _why_ the semantics of `std::numeric_limits<>::min()` are different for floating point and for integral types.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I like your now-deleted answer, any chance of undeleting?

Comment: @GManNickG Done.  I deleted it because it didn't actually answer the question, which I'd misunderstood to mean why wasn't it returning `-DBLMAX`.  On the other hand, it does explain a bit of the history, and why `std::numeric_limits<>::min()` behaves so differently for floating point and integral types.  (I think it would be a good answer to a different question.)

Answer (score 11):

Historical reasons.  `std::numeric_limits` was originally built
around the contents of `<limits.h>` (where you have e.g.
`INT_MIN`) and `<float.h>` (where you have e.g. `DBL_MIN`).
These two files were (I suspect) designed by different people;
people doing floating point don't need a separate most positive
and most negative value, because the most negative is always the
negation of the most positive, but they do need to know the
smallest value greater than 0.  Regretfully, the values have the
same pattern for the name, and `std::numeric_limits` ended up
defining the semantics of `min` differently depending on
`std::numeric_limits<>::is_integer`.

This makes template programming more awkward, you keep having to
do things like `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer ? std::numeric_limits<T>::min() : -std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`
so C++11 adds `std::numeric_limits<>::lowest()`, which does
exactly what you'd expect.

Comment: including a std::numeric_limits<T>::highest() method, even as a syntactic sugar for std::numeric_limits<T>::max() would have been great, for the sake of consistency in naming conventions.